# Detecting tapped character. UITextView characterRangeAtPoint always returns nil

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uikit, core-text

I'm trying to determine, which particular character in `UITextView` has been tapped. I tried to use `characterRangeAtPoint:` method. But it always returns nil, wherever in the `UITextView` I tap.
I even wrote and run the following piece of code:

```
for (int x = 0; x<1000; x++) {
    pos.x = x;
    for (int y = 0; y<1000; y++) {
        pos.y = y;
        UITextRange * range = [textView characterRangeAtPoint:pos];
        if (range!=nil) {
            NSLog(@"x: %f, y: %f", pos.x, pos.y);
        }
    }
}
```

Well, it never reaches the `NSLog` string.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an iOS 7 bug. `characterRangeAtPoint:` always returns `nil`, unless some text has been selected at least once beforehand.

As a workaround, you could call `setSelectedRange:` or `setSelectedTextRange:` beforehand, but then the `textView` would highlight your selection. I came up with the following solution:

```
[textView select:textView];
[textView setSelectedTextRange:nil];
```

After you call these two methods, `characterRangeAtPoint:` will start working as expected.

Note that you just need to call this once after `textView` has been initialized.

**EDIT:** my answer was edited from *"unless some text has been selected beforehand"* to *"unless some text is currently selected"*. This is wrong: text doesn't need to be currently selected, it just has to be selected once. All subsequent calls to `setSelectedRange:` will then be successful, as stated in my note. Edited back for further clarity.

Answer (score 5):

Your UITextView must be selectable. In storyboard, check the "Selectable" checkbox.

In code,

```
textView.selectable = YES;
```

This is also required for the `-closestPositionToPoint:` method on UITextView.

Answer (score 0):

Use shouldChangeCharactersInRange method instead of characterRangeAtPoint.

And use your If condition inplace of loop statement.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see, how shouldChangeCharactersInRange could help me find the dependence between touch coordingates and character ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Is your TextView user-editable?
If YES, then try the `texViewDidChangeSelection` method. It is invoked every time the caret(cursor) is moved in a textView. Then get the cursor position by `textView.selectedRange.location` to point to the index, of the caret.

My assumption here is that you want the location of the character with respect to the number of character, and not co-ordinates in 2D.

Comment: No, my intention is to override the native selection behaviour. So I need mapping from CGPoint to UITextRange (or NSRange, whatever).