# In IOS 7, UITextView offsetFromPosition: toPosition: always return 0 with arguments of UITextPositions returned from UITextView characterRangeAtPoint

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uitextview, ios7

I was trying to use `UITextView characterRangeAtPoint` in my code to get `UITextRanges` at some `CGPoints` within the textview. And then I used the `UITextPositions` from those `UITextRanges` as arguments and used `UITextView offsetFromPosition: toPosition:` to get the offset.  It worked well in iOS 6. But when I tried it in iOS 7, it always returned me `offset 0` no matter what `CGPoint` I tried within the textview.

Here is the code:

```
// init the textview
textview = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 500)];
textview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:textview];

// load the txt file for testing  
NSError *error;
NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"txt"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"load string error:%@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
    return;
}

// set the text and font
textview.text = content;
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
textview.font = font;

// get text range at point (100, 100) and string offset from the beginning to this point 
UITextRange *textrange = [textview characterRangeAtPoint: CGPointMake(100, 100)];
NSInteger offset = [textview offsetFromPosition:textview.beginningOfDocument toPosition:textrange.start];
NSLog(@"offset = %d", offset);
```

The `offset` it returned was always `0`. In order to test if it was because of `UITextView offsetFromPosition: toPosition:`, I tried the following code:

```
NSInteger offset1 = [textview offsetFromPosition:textview.beginningOfDocument toPosition:textview.endOfDocument];
NSLog(@"offset1 = %d", offset1);
```

it gave me `offset1 = 5264`, which was correct according to the `test.txt` I used. So the problem is the `UITextRange` returned from `textview characterRangeAtPoint`. It seemed that in IOS 7 the `characterRangeAtPoint` didn't return me the correct text range at the given `CGPoint`. So `textview offsetFromPosition: toPosition:` couldn't return the correct offset.

But I used the same code in IOS 6 and it worked very well. I also checked the reference of `characterRangeAtPoint`, but found no useful information.

Does anyone know what happened with `characterRangeAtPoint` in IOS 7? In order to make it functional as it was in IOS 6, what should I do?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate - [Detecting tapped character. UITextView characterRangeAtPoint always returns nil](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18925755).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting tapped character. UITextView characterRangeAtPoint always returns nil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925755/detecting-tapped-character-uitextview-characterrangeatpoint-always-returns-nil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met the same issue. And I found that characterRangeAtPoint wouldn't return a value unless text has been changed or selected at least once in the TextView in IOS 7. 
I can't make this function to work properly so I had to avoid to use it(I tried to set setContentInset as well but no luck). And here is my workaround. I believe you can make something similar to fit your situation.

```
// get the beginning position of the current line.
NSRange pos = [textView.text rangeOfString:@"\n" options:NSBackwardsSearch range:NSMakeRange(0,textView.selectedRange.location)];
if (pos.location == NSNotFound) pos.location = 0; // if the text has only one line.
NSLog(@"pos = %d",pos.location);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I found that information when I googled this topic. So would you mind to let me know how did you solve your problem? I also found closestPositionToPoint also does similar thing as characterRangeAtPoint. And it can return correct value even if the textview hasn't been selected. However, when the point's y you passes to this method becomes larger (in my test case, the point's y  is over 260pt), the return value becomes incorrect. That's so weird...in iOS 6, closestPositionToPoint works pretty well.

Comment: @boatflag, I hope this is helpful :)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply! And thanks a lot for sharing your solution! My case is a little different from yours. I need to display the text in pages, so I need to know how many characters can fit in one page before I draw text. Finally I wrote a function based on boundingRectWithSize. But your solution is also a good way to solve this problem for case that's similar to yours. So I will select your solution as an answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Set the setContentInset of your textview

try this code

```
UITextRange *textrange = [textview characterRangeAtPoint: CGPointMake(100, 100)];
NSInteger offset = [textview offsetFromPosition:textview.beginningOfDocument toPosition:textrange.start];

[textview setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-45, 0, 5,0)];

NSLog(@"offset = %d", offset);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried your code, but the offset was still 0. Could you please explain how the contentInset would affect characterRangeAtPoint? Thanks!

Comment: this code is work in Ios7, I am already check.....Please change the CGPointMake(10000, 10000)

Comment: I have no idea why mines didn't work... and change the CGPoint to (10000, 10000) makes the point outside the textview (I tried that also, still returned 0). I think (100, 100) is a reasonable position according to the textview in my code, and I could get correct offset on iOS 6 device. Could you please tell me why setContentInset would affect the result returned by characterRangeAtPoint?

Comment: I googled this topic, and found someone said characterRangeAtPoint wouldn't return a value unless text has been selected at least once in the TextView in IOS 7. Is that true? I would really appreciate if you could give me more explanation. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this bug, and posted a solution as a reply to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925755/detecting-tapped-character-uitextview-characterrangeatpoint-always-returns-nil).

Here's a copy-paste:

---

This is an iOS 7 bug. `characterRangeAtPoint:` always returns nil, unless text was selected beforehand.

As a workaround, you could call `setSelectedRange:` or `setSelectedTextRange:` beforehand, but then the textView would highlight your selection. I came up with the following solution:

```
[textView select:textView];
[textView setSelectedTextRange:nil];
```

After you call these two methods, `characterRangeAtPoint:` will start working as expected.

Note that you just need to call this once after `textView` has been initialized.

Comment: Simply copying the content of another answer on [so] is not particularly appropriate as an answer. If you feel this question is a duplicate of another question, you should flag it as such.

Comment: @Dukeling , I don't have enough reputation to flag a question as duplicate, and I felt like the "link plus paste" approach would be a decent compromise (considering I'm pasting my own answer, not someone else's).

Comment: I added a link as a comment on the question, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issues lately developing for 7.1.1 (still not fixed...) and wanted to share my easy solution.

I tried What Exile.90 did and it didn't work.

Instead I enabled text selection in the storyboard and disabled it during viewDidLoad. No selection happens but the affected functions are working perfectly for me now.